TraceServer throws this exception: "Failed to get SQL Tools directory path from InstAPI"
I need to create a SQL Trace in C# so that I can capture the database traffic as I would've in SQL Profiler, and save it in to a file but I am getting the above error when running my code.
Below is a simple code that creates a ServerTrace and initialises the reader so that a trace can be used. The code compiles but when running the code, trace.InitializeAsReader throws the above exception (see stracktrace below).
The server I have this code and running on it, has Visual Studio (v15 & 22), SSMS (not SQL instance - v17.9) and SQL Profiler (v14) installed and I can connect to a SQL Instance on a different server with SSMS and can open a trace to any database on this instance through SQL Profiler.
Although I have used SQL profiler for a long time, I am new to creating a trace programmatically.
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management
The following are the assemblies I have referenced for these libraries. Also as a test, I have tried referencing these from the project folder as well as from GAC which did not make any difference:
instapi140.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll and Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended.dll
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

namespace PolMate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                ConnectionInfoBase connectioninfo = new SqlConnectionInfo();
                //populate connectioninfo with the connection string details


            TraceServer trace = new TraceServer();
                trace.InitializeAsReader(conninfo, "c:\\temp\\Standard.tdf")

                for (int count = 0; count < 30; count++)
                {
                    while (trace.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(trace["TextData"]);
                    }

           
                }
        }

        public void StartTrace()
        {
            trace.Restart();
        }

        public void StopTrace()
        {
            trace.Stop();
        }

        public void SaveTraceToFile(string filePath)
        {
            trace.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
}

I have done a lot of websearch on this error but every one pointing me to SQL Tools however I have not seen a practical resolution that helps.
I did also experimented with VS2015 with SQL Trace version 12 and 14.
There are two question on this topic that no one has offered any solution.The following is one of the two that reflects my scenario to and I have applied the recommendations. I am not using SQL Express.
TraceServer class fails to initialize as reader when pointing at local SQL Server Express


Why not use the native trace components? sp_trace_create and friends? Also, put the whole stacktrace into the question, this isn't highlight magazine

Thanks @siggemannen
"Why not use the native trace components?": this app is a stand-alone app separate to the main app that talks to the sql server.
Stacktrace has been added to the question.

Well, whatever SMO does it will still call the trace procedures eventually. Btw, which SMO version are you using?

"which SMO version?": Nuget package "Unofficial Microsoft Sql Server Management Objects" version 17.4.1.
I have tried using the DLLs installed in my server as well but no difference.
